# Karma Angular.js unit test expectPUT

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I've got a problem with unit tests using karma.

```
  $httpBackend.expectPUT(envConfig.restUrl + 'customers/1').respond(200);
  it('should update"customer details" model', function() {
      expect(scope.customerDetails).toBeUndefined();
      $httpBackend.flush();
```

and the response:

```
 Error: Unsatisfied requests: PUT undefinedcustomers/1
 at Function.$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation
```

Comment: is `envConfig.restUrl` defined ?

Comment: There is no problem - you are expecting some PUT calling but in never occurs -  `$httpBackend.flush()` tries to flush all request but there is no pending request.

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski Look at the url being requested => `PUT undefinedcustomers/1`

Comment: @ashish look at `it` section - there is nothing that can execute PUT query

Comment: Yup that is correct changing it to `whenPUT` might fix it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `envConfig.restUrl` is not defined.

As per @KrzysztofSafjanowski comment you're also not calling a function which might do that `PUT` request or doing that manually. Changing it to `whenPUT` might fix that :

```
$httpBackend.whenPUT(envConfig.restUrl + 'customers/1').respond(200);
  it('should update"customer details" model', function() {
      expect(scope.customerDetails).toBeUndefined();
      $httpBackend.flush();
```

Comment: it is defined. expectGET tests are successful

Comment: @kret No - it is not defined - show more / full test code, so we can try to find source of error

Comment: @kret I don't know - it depends what you are trying to do. Please make some example like http://stackoverflow.com/a/31316620/2708895 and will will try to figure out what is wrong